# Creating buttons on button click in QT

Tags: c++, qt, button, qt-creator, qpushbutton

How can I do this? I want to create a button by pressing another button, but in the current code of my, I can just create one button and the button I've created it, dissapears.

How could i dynamically do this? Pls help, I'm kinda new to Qt.

That's the main part of it:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->button1->setVisible(false);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
    delete ui; }


void MainWindow::on_multiplyButton_clicked()
{
    ui->button1->setVisible(true);
}
```

In this way the button just appears, but that doesn't seem like a solution to me, if i would want to scale it. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2KRZ.jpg)

With every click on the multiply a new button should appear.

Comment: You should edit your question with your current code so we can better understand your problem (see [MCVE](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiPw7bFo6fOAhWCvRQKHYN_Dz4QFghUMAc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fhelp%2Fmcve&usg=AFQjCNEkKReghNZHBJSaky_hwPskMmG0ww&sig2=9anXjmzNVE4wrvj6MgRs2Q))

Comment: You're right, is it more understandable now?

Comment: Note that you shouldn't be using `QMainWindow` unless you need the dockable subwindow functionality it offers. You should otherwise use a `QDialog` or `QWidget` as the base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the designer and ui files. Here is a "full code" proposition:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    public:
        MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

        void on_multiplyButton_clicked();

    private:
        QBoxLayout *layout;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):QMainWindow(parent) {
    // create multiply button
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(tr("Push me hard"));
    connect(
        button, &QPushButton::clicked,
        this  , &MainWindow ::on_multiplyButton_clicked
    );

    // initialize button container
    this->layout = new QHBoxLayout; // or QVBoxLayout if you prefer
    this->layout->addWidget(button);

    // set central widget of the main window
    QWidget *central_widget = new QWidget;
    central_widget->setLayout(this->layout);
    this->setCentralWidget(central_widget);
}

void MainWindow::on_multiplyButton_clicked() {
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(
        tr("button%1").arg(this->layout->count())
    );
    this->layout->addWidget(button);
}
```